# Given four tables, with two key tables, any way to join them for a particular scenario?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables:

```
Table_1: Date (Date: 'YYYYMMDD'), 
         Path_Id (Int: 3, primary key for path), 
         Size (Bigint: 12932943, size of directory)

Table_2: Date (Date: 'YYYYMMDD'), 
         Path_Id (Int: 9, primary key for path), 
         User_Id (Int: 3, primary key for user)
         Count (Int: 282, number of times file has been opened)

Table_3: id (Primary Key)
         Path (String: '/user/tom', a directory path)
           OR (String: '/user/tom/logs/file.txt', a file path)

Table_4: id (Primary Key)
         User (String: 'tom')
```

The goal is to come up with a final table joined by date with the following output:

```
     Date     |     Path     |     Size     |     User     |     Count    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-10-14    |/user/tom     |12932943      |tom           |92423
2019-10-14    |/user/tom     |12932943      |gary          |1093
2019-10-14    |/user/tom/logs|892310        |tom           |423
.
.
.
```

where Path is the column of all paths from Table_1 with the corresponding Size from Table_1, User and Count are from Table_2 but they are calculated by taking the Path from Table_1 and looking for all Paths in Table_2 that start with the Path from Table_1. More precisely for every Path in Table_1,
I'm getting:

```
SELECT t2.Date AS Date, 
       "/for/some/directory" AS Path,
       t4.User AS User, 
       t2.Count AS Count 
FROM Table_2 t2, Table_3 t3, Table_4 t4
WHERE t2.Path_Id = t3.Path_Id AND
      t2.User_Id = t4.User_Id AND
      t3.Path LIKE CONCAT("/for/some/directory", "%")
```

My question is how do I generalize this for all paths so I can get the expected output. This is a bit difficult since I have two tables that need the same table for paths but the paths I need to look at for each of them are not the same.

Comment: why gary has a path /user/tom?

Comment: Don't you simply need to not hard code the path, and report t3.path instead? Oh, and of course change your table,table,table syntax to proper join syntax that replaced the old version 25 years ago. But that goes without saying.

Comment: `"/for/some/directory" AS Path,` will not work with Postgres. Did you mean to write `'/for/some/directory' AS Path,`?